# Reusing EF entities for both EF 6.x and EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a project on .NET 4.8 and EF 6.4.4. We are gradually migrating to .Net Core but during the process can I create a .NET Core data context class, EF Core and point both to same entities?

Comment: Yes but I would recommend you place the entities (models) in a shared project with the target frameworks of netstandard2.0 and net4.8. Make sure there is no EF specific code in your models, they should be pure POCO types (plain old clr objects). All mappings should be done using fluent mappings in your EF implementations.

Comment: seems like NET Core can't work with  netstandard2.0

Comment: What version of .net core are you using?

Comment: my start is 4.8 and EF 6.4.4, I am looking for any combination of Core and Standard to reuse existing entities

Comment: I have a .NET Core 3.1 project that references a project that targets .NET Standard 2.0. No problems here so I am not sure what you mean that it cant work.

Comment: .NET Core 3.1 with EF Core?

Comment: .net core 3.1 (its an mvc project) → .net standard 2.0 (uses EF core) → .net standard 2.0 (shared poco types).

Comment: And then a .net 4.8 framework projects that then also use the same shared poco library.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227045/discussion-between-toolkit-and-igor).

Comment: What flow are you using? Code first? Db first? Model first?

Comment: @Artur Code first

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Refer to the diagram below.

0. Convert all libraries to `.netstandard2.0`
1. Start by moving all models to separate project.
2. Then create new project where you are going to migrate your dal classes to EF Core (I'd recommend to keep the same namespace in `Dal.csproj` and `Dal.Core.csproj` so consumers won't be affected).
3. Move your first dal class from `Dal.csproj` to `Dal.Core.csproj`. Now Stage + Commit - this is very important step, otherwise you will loose git history for this class. Now you can do all required changes to make it work with new `DbContext`
4. Once you finish all migrations move everything from `Dal.Core.csproj` back to `Dal.csproj` and remove `Dal.Core.csproj` project. Do not forget to stage changes before commit so git will recognize moved files as rename rather than delete+add.

**Tip**: make sure you are aware of [Cartesian Explosion Problem](https://www.thinktecture.com/en/entity-framework-core/cartesian-explosion-problem-in-3-1/) in EF Core 3

**Note**: if you are working in Model First approach with EDMX file that's not supported in EF Core, you can't convert the project with EDMX to `netstandard2.0` and should keep it as `net48`.

[image]

Comment: And with EF 5 you can choose whether `Include` generates "Single" or "Split" queries. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/single-split-queries